# For any compact $K \subset G$ open, how to show that there exist $R > 0$ s.t. $B(a;R) \subset G$ for all $a\in K$?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I think it's correct, at least in $\Bbb{R}^n$. It is a gap of another of my proof, and at first I didn't bother to show it and thought it is obvious. However when I tried to write an argument I was lost. I intend to use finite covering property to say we can find minimum distance, but only the "existence" of finite cover seems not good enough for the optimized one. Then if I use infimum of them, it is not necessary to be $>0$. Even with closed and boundedness this is still a problem.

Comment: Does your title say that we let $G$ be open?

Comment: @WillFisher Yes I just edited

Comment: Doesn't this simply follow from the fact that $G$ is open and $K\subset G$? Since $a\in K$, $a\in G$, and so $a$ is an interior point of $G$ since $G$ is open and thus $G$ contains a neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: $K \subset G$ is clearly not enough. An open subset "touching the boundary" of the original one doesn't have a universal radius that every neighborhood can sit in. Well, $K=G$ is an example.

Comment: Oh apologies, I didn't see that you wanted a fixed radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fact that if $K$ is compact and $F$ is closed in a metric space $X$ with $K$ and $F$ disjoint, then $d(K,F) = \inf d(x,y) > 0$ where the inf is taken over all $x\in K$ and $y\in F$. Apply this result to $K$ and $G^c$, the complement of $G$ to obtain that $d(K,G^c) > R > 0$ for some $R > 0$. Hence any ball of radius $R$ around a point in $K$ will be contained in $G$.

To prove this fact, consider the function $\delta:K\to \Bbb R$ defined by $\delta(x) = d(x,F) = \inf_{y\in F}d(x,y)$. The function $\delta$ satisfies $|\delta(x) - \delta(y)| \le d(x,y)$, so it is clearly continuous. A continuous function on a compact set obtains its infimum, so put $\alpha = \inf_{x\in K}\delta(x)$. Use the fact that $F$ is closed to conclude that $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that the last part requires $K$ and $F$ be disjoint.

Comment: @WillFisher nice catch

Comment: Oh, complement, nice idea!